# Response.HeadersWritten in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I understand whether the response headers have been written in ASP.NET Core 2? In classic ASP.NET is [HttpResponse.HeadersWritten Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.headerswritten?view=netframework-4.7.2), but seems like there is no one in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: [`HttpResponse.HasStarted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.hasstarted?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpResponse_HasStarted)

Comment: `HttpResponse.Headers.IsReadOnly`?